# Проблема с использованием os.chdir

Tags: python

Ошибка FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$HOME/.cache'

```
...
os.chdir("$HOME/.cache")
...
```

хотелось бы понять в чем дело, т.к. cd $HOME/.cache дает нужный результат

Comment: используйте `os.path.expandvars()` для преобразования переменных.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно :)